# AdMob's Monetize tab doesn't show "Allow & Block Ads"

Tags: android, admob

I was trying to add a filter to the Ads in AdMob and I read that I need to do that in the "Allow & Block Ads" section. But when I go to the Monetize tab in https://apps.admob.com, it doesn't show me "Allow & Block Ads". Can anyone please let me know why this is happening so.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This isn't related to programming per se.  You should probably consult [AdMob help](https://support.google.com/admob/?hl=en#topic=3309392)

Comment: Thanks. Will do now on but for all who are facing the same issue @Uwais A has given the correct Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you need to click `All Apps` on the left then the `Allow & block ads` menu comes up. Not sure why this isn't more clearly labelled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Appreciate your quick response. Yes, its not very intuitive.I felt I could customize each App and never clicked on All Apps.

Comment: No problem - yeah, I'm pretty sure that's how it used to be, I didn't notice it change until I looked for an answer to this question.